# enum class with switch statement

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an enum class

```
enum class ENUM{ A, B, C};
```

And I want to have a switch statement. So I get

```
char c = 'B';
ENUM e = ENUM::A;
switch(e) {
    case A:
    break;
    case B:
    break;
    case C:
    break;
}
```

The case could never be B. But how to convert value `c` to be enum value?

Comment: char B is `0x42`, ENUM::B is 1.

Comment: _"... But how to convert value c to be enum value?"_ create a mapper class, that supports that conversion.

Comment: @273K good hint!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
enum class ENUM{ A = 'A', B = 'B', C = 'C' };
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You said "convert `c` to enum value", so I assume you want to use Switch statement with a character.

You may just `switch (c)`.

Comment: except that the value of c in this case will not be a value of a member of the enum